# React Native: Ionicons not showing in iOS simulator

Tags: react-native

Here is my code for the *back to previous screen* button.

```
// ChevronLeftButton.tsx
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, StyleSheet, GestureResponderEvent } from 'react-native';
import Ionicons from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';

type ChevronLeftButtonProps = {
  onPress: (event: GestureResponderEvent) => void;
  color?: string;
  size?: number;
};

const ChevronLeftButton: React.FC<ChevronLeftButtonProps> = ({
  onPress,
  color = 'black', // default color
  size = 25, // default size
}) => {
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={onPress}>
      <Ionicons name="chevron-back" size={size} color={color} />
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    position: 'absolute',  // Position the button absolutely within its container
    top: 50,
    left: 12,
    padding: 10, // Add padding for a larger touch area
    color: 'white'
  },
});

export default ChevronLeftButton;
```

The icon is showed as per the picture.

I ran successfully `yarn add react-native-vector-icons` and the app is showing no warning / errors.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This because you haven't added the Font files to your Info.plist file yet. Please refer the articles available online for doing this. It'll also contain images for better understanding. But here are the steps involved:

### Step 1: Open the project in Xcode

- open project-name-folder/ios/project-name.xcworkspace
- or open Xcode and navigate to your project folder

[image]

[image]

- Right-click on the project folder, choose 'New Group,' and name it 'Fonts.'
  Navigate to node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/Fonts
- Drag and drop .ttf font files into the 'Fonts' folder in Xcode. In this case, your Ionicons.ttf file
- Ensure 'Copy items if needed' and 'Create folder references' are selected. Click 'Finish.'

[image]

### Step 2: Configure Xcode

- Open 'Info.plist' under project-name folder in Xcode
- Click '+' in 'Information Property List,' choose 'Add Row,' name it 'Fonts provided by application.'
- Click '+' next to 'Fonts provided by application' and add an item for each font file.
- Write full font file name (e.g., Ionicons.ttf) in the value section of each item.

[image]

[image]

### Step 3: Pod Updating

Update your pods by running the pod update command

`cd ios`

`sudo pod update`

Return to Xcode, select 'Product' > 'Clean Build Folder' from the menu bar, and then run the app.

[image]

You should be able to see the icons now. If not, close/terminate the terminals rebuild the app once again using
`npx react-native run-ios`.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I am using vscode as an IDE, although I did go to Xcode and followed your steps, still didn't work. I also added UIAppFonts in my Info.plist containing <key>UIAppFonts</key><array<string>AntDesign.ttf</string><string>Entypo.ttf</string> etc.. Still no luck after pod install and rebuilding the app

Comment: I am surprised how can it be so complex, and how there isn't any logging for that.

Comment: @EtienneHerlaut, could you please search for 'Change permissions for files, folders or disks on Mac'. And then for the whole Project folder, set 'Me', 'Staff', and 'Everyone' to 'Read & Write' and then Apply permissions to all items in a folder or a disk. Sometimes, when you add the font.ttf files from node_modules, and they don't have the right permissions, this could happen. Once you do this, please do the whole process of dragging the font files once again and try rebuilding it. It should work.